# maintaining versions of the ADF pipelines

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have an end to end pipeline created in ADF to fetch the files process them and project them to power BI, wanted to maintain the versioning of this pipeline.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need create ADF resource with Git configuration to save current version of ADF end to end Pipeline.

[image]

You can also save ARM template of your pipeline and later create new resource with Git Configuration.